# Google Chrome no longer opens after 14.04 update

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I just updated to 14.04 today, and when I restarted my computer I got a few "report a problem" messages. I didn't think too much of them until I tried to open Google Chrome from the launcher, and it wont open anymore. I don't know if it's because of the update or not, so if anyone can help me out that would be great

Comment: What version did you upgrade to 14.04 from? 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Run at your Terminal.

**Download & add the key**:

```
wget -q -O – https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Add Chrome repository to your** `sources.list`:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

**Update sources**:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install with** `--reinstall --fix-broken --show-progress`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -f --show-progress google-chrome-stable
```

For simple install just omit these three options.

Comment: Done. Sorry, `--fix-broken` option, corrected.